# How to remove an item in SelectListItem

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to remove an item from selectlistitem.
so far, I have not gotten any success

Here is the snapshot of codes

using System.Collections.Generic;

```
        List<SelectListItem> abcd = new List<SelectListItem>();
        SelectListItem i1 = null;
        i1 = new SelectListItem();
        i1.Text = "t0";
        i1.Value = "v0";
        i1.Selected = false;
        abcd.Add(i1);
        i1 = new SelectListItem();
        i1.Text = "";
        i1.Value = "";
        i1.Selected = false;
        abcd.Add(i1);
        i1 = new SelectListItem();
        i1.Text = "t1";
        i1.Value = "v1";
        i1.Selected = false;
        abcd.Add(i1);
```

I've tried to remove one of the abcd item that matches with:

```
        SelectListItem f = new SelectListItem();
        f.Selected = false;
        f.Text = "t0";
        f.Value = "v0";
        f.Selected = false;

        int x = abcd.IndexOf(f);  //return -1
        bool b = abcd.Remove(f); //return false
```

... but it did not remove.
I tried to find the index, and it always return -1
Since I don't know the position of a particular list, removeat method will not help.

Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you correctly this should work. You will want to modify this to handle situations where there are multiple SelectListItem values with the value you want to remove, or if no SelectListItem has your value.

```
abcd.Remove(abcd.Where(c => c.Value == "v0").Single());
```

Or

```
abcd = abcd.Where(c => c.Value != "v0").ToList();
```

Or

```
abcd.RemoveAll(c => c.Value == "v0");
```

Comment: Single will throw an exception when there are multiple items in the list matching the predicate what is possible here. So use `First()` instead.

Comment: @TimSchmelter As I noted in my answer. I also provided alternative answers that wouldn't have these problems.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think that removing a **new** instance of a `SelectListItem` from the list that happens to have the same values as an existing item will cause the existing item to be removed.  This is wrong.  You're going to have to either hang on to a reference to the existing one (`i1`) or find it first and remove it.  The latter approach would look like (for one item):

```
abcd.Remove(abcd.Single(x => x.Value == "v0"));
```

Or (for multiple):

```
abcd.RemoveRange(abcd.Where(x => x.Value == "v0"));
```

Comment: Why are you using `Single` instead of `First`? I assume it's possible that there are multiple items with the same value in the list.

Comment: I've personally never done that, but I suppose you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In reference types X.Properties = Y.Properties doesn't mean that X=Y so :

```
SelectListItem f = abcd.Find(Itm=>Itm.Text == "t0" && Itm.Value == "v0" &&  Itm.Selected == false)
```

and adapt your condition to your needs 
then

```
    int x = abcd.IndexOf(f);  //return -1
    bool b = abcd.Remove(f); //return false
```